# How to insert hidden text in QLabel?

Tags: qt, qlabel, richtext

In a QLabel, I have some rich text with some superscript (e.g. kg m<sup>-3</sup>). If this text is copied and pasted in a plain text editor, the pasted text is `kg m-3`. I would like the pasted text to be `kg m^-3`. Is there any way to insert `^` as a hidden text in-between `m` and `-3`? I looked at some hidden text tags in rich text format but these don't seem to work in Qt.

```
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;    
  QLabel *l = new QLabel(w);
  l->setText("kg m<sup>-3</sup>");
  l->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
  w->setCentralWidget(l);        
  w->show();    
  app.exec();
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Qlabels are readonly text from "users Point of view"... how are you copying that?

Comment: I have added sample code. I want to be able to copy the label text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the following line:

```
l->setText("kg m<html><font style="font-size:1px">^</font></html><sup>-3</sup>");
```

Using `font-size:0px` gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Without inserting the '^' character as 'hidden text' you could probably connect the signal [QPlainTextEdit::textChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#textChanged*) to a slot function that processes the text. To process the text i would suggest a simple RegExp.

All of this would look something like (Warning: code NOT tested):

Connect the signal to the slot function (the function to process the string has to be declared as a slot)

```
QObject::connect(plainTextEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(processRichString());
```

Define the function for the processing as follows

```
void MyClass::processRichString()
{
  QString strToProcess = label->toPlainText();
  QRegExp rx("<sup>(.*)</sup>");
  strToProcess.replace(rx, "^\\1");
  label->setPlainText(strToProcess);
}
```